# How to add trademark symbol to project name in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

Is it possible to add a trademark symbol to project name in Doxygen?

```
PROJECT_NAME = "Company Product Name(tm)"
```

This appears as the home page title, and it would be very nice to have trademark symbol there.

p.s.
This does not work:

```
PROJECT_NAME = "Company Product Name&tm;"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `&trade;` instead of `&tm;`.

Doxygen's support for the trademark appears to be incomplete / inconsistent.

`&tm;` is documented as a supported character entity by Doxygen, but it isn't specified by HTML 4.0. This character entity is rendered correctly in the body of the document, but is not handled correct in the page header.

`&#8482;` and `&#153;` are the entity number representations of ™ supported by HTML 4.0, however entity number representations are not supported by Doxygen, they will be rendered correctly in the page header, but will not be handled by doxygen in the body of the document.

`&trade;` is the character entity in HTML 4.0 for ™, however it is not listed as a supported character entity in Doxygen. Luckily, this appears to be an error in the documentation as `&trade;` is handled correctly in both the page header and the body of the document.